# About Use different rules and for different form yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a form for user registration and change password, but I want to get this different scenario in my controller:

```php
public function rules()
{
   return [
       [['username', 'password_hash', 'email'], 'required'],
       [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
       [['username', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email'],     'string', 'max' => 255],
       [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
       [['username'], 'unique'],
       [['email'], 'unique'],
       [['email'], 'email'],
       [['password_reset_token'], 'unique'],

       //rules for change Password
       [['oldPassword', 'newPassword', 'confirmPassword'], 'required', 'on' =>'change_password'],
       //check user input password is validate with database password
       [['oldPassword'], 'validateOldPassword', 'on' =>'change_password'],

       [['newPassword'], 'string', 'min' => 6 , 'on' => 'change_password'],
       [['newPassword'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim', 'on' => 'change_password'],
       [['confirmPassword'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'newPassword','message'=>'Password did not match', 'on' => 'change_password'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: so, you don't know how to use in controller?

Comment: Yap,Even i am not sure my model is right.

Comment: Just read the [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios).

Answer (score 3):

In Model you have to specify scenarios like the following.
For example while registering name,email and password will be required.
Consider on login only email and password is required

```
<?php
    public function rules(){
            return [
                [['email','password'],'required','on'=>'login'],
                [['name', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => 'register'],
                ];

    ?>
     <?php

        class MainController extends Controller
        {
          public function actionLogin(){
           $model = new User();
           $model->scenario = 'login';
        } 

         public function actionRegister(){
         $model = new User();
         $model->scenario = 'register';
       }

    }
?>
```

Visit [Scenarios](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-scenarios/) link

Comment: Thanks everyone for response

But my mistake is change password is for already existing user and i get solution is 


        $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
        //check validation scenario change_password of model User
        $user->scenario = User::SCENARIO_PASSWORD;

Thank You

Comment: This has really helped and is working perfectly. Many thanks